# Access to audio from audio card with WebRTC

Tags: audio, webrtc

I'd like to be able to capture the audio from the audio card of my computer and to dispatch it with WebRTC. However, I am not sure if it's possible or not to have access to the audio directly produced by my computer.

According to this repo https://github.com/niklasenbom/RecordingApp/blob/master/app.js there is a system audio stuff but not sure if it's what I'm looking for.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio). Actually I did the same project myself and will put it in GitHub in a few weeks and update this answer. You can configure the frequency etc. and use it's  `OnDataAvailable` event to dispatch the sound to registered clients.

Comment: I'd like it to be web based - that's why I've been looking at WebRTC.

Comment: You can use this library to record the audio (serverside of course) that goes through your audio card and stream it with WebRTC. But if you wonder that how you can record audio that goes though the sound card by using WebRTC, that not going to happen..

Comment: @sotn Is necessary record the audio with NAudio to stream it with WebRTC? There is no option to do it (stream "what you hear") using WebRTC direclty?

Comment: @jgd Streaming "what you hear" means reading the raw data before it goes through your sound card and processing that raw data to get an appropriate encoding like mp3 and then streaming it which WebRTC cannot do because it cannot access your computer's resources like that..

Comment: @sotn But WebRTC have in chromium project, a class to capture audio using loopback audio capture defined WASAPI. AFAIK, chromium can stream loopback audio capture through WebRTC so that mean it can be possible. What your opinion about?

Comment: @jgd It's about how much the browsers utilize and take advantage of WebRTC. I don't have an idea about that class in chromium project that you're referring to but think of it like this: Can WebRTC be used to manage printer with peer to peer connection (printing something, keeping track of the prints in real time etc.), of course.. as long as chrome expands it's apis and support accessing printer resources of the computers.. The only way that you can do what you're trying to do (imho) is using [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) with chrome extensions..